# Android - findViewById method in fragment to find an item from a custom layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, findviewbyid

First of all, I've searched on many other posts and still not found a fix for it.

`MainActivity` is a tabbed activity (2 tabs) and the first one contains a `ListView`. A single item from that list is made from a **custom_row layout file** that contains an `ImageView` with id **deleteItemImage**.

How to use findViewById in `Tab1_class` to get the reference to that image from a custom layout file in order to be able to `setOnClickListener(...)`?

I've already tried to use (on `onCreateView(...)` method) `view.findViewById(...)` or `getActivity().findViewById(...)` or `getView().findViewById(...)` and nothing works.

Hope someone can help!! Thank you in advance!!

**EDIT:**

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    (...)
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteItemImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tab1_List.java

```
(...)
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_list, container, false);

        (...)
        //TODO
        ImageView deleteItemImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.deleteItemImage);
        deleteItemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // ...
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the xml and the java file where you try to find the view

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Edit: code above.

Comment: You inflate `tab1_list.xml` but try to find an element that is inside `custom_row.xml` that cannot work. Where is the row inflated?

Comment: @Altoyyr I did <code>View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, container, false);</code> and it isn't giving an error (thanks!) but when I click on it nothing happen and <code>setOnClickListener()</code> is there...

Comment: there is no point in inflating the custom list row layout in onCreateView. You should simply use Adapter(RecyclerAdapter or ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter)

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay That's not the point, I omitted that part. Thought it was useless to show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare Listener interface for adapter item.
and implements TouchListener in Tab1_class.

I hope following code will help ...

Modify your Adapter class and ViewHolder, like

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener{

        private ImageView iv_cardImage;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_cardImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cardImage);
            iv_cardImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "from adapter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    touchListener.itemTouched(view, getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setTouchListener(TouchListener touchListener){
        this.touchListener = touchListener;
    }
```

Create an Interface to be called when item imageview is clicked

```
public interface TouchListener{
        void itemTouched(View v, int position);
    }
```